# Mongodb VS Redis - Performance benchmarks - Which DB should be used for Cache?

Tags: mongodb, caching, redis, mongodb-java

I am working on finalizing on the caching layer which we need to use for our application. we have shortlisted 2 for now Redis and Mongodb. I am not sure which one to be used as a cache. So for that i thought of doing a performance testing for both and then compare based on the results.

Now, I have been reading a lot about the advantages of each and it looks like the recommended approach is to go with Mongodb as a data storage layer and Redis as a cache layer which sits in front of the web application to avoid requests hitting the origin.

I have shared the results below.

But based on my performance results, redis performance is no where close to that of mongodb. So can we safely say that mongodb would be a better choice for caching then redis?

Please let me know what you guys think. Also I am no expert in Redis or mongodb so please let me know if I am doing anything wrong in redis or mongodb.

I can fix and redo the test again.

Host Configuration:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Intel Core i5 2520M CPU 2.50Ghz
- RAM 16GB

[image]

Redis Version:3.2.1 (Windows 64 bit version)
Mongo Version:3.2.5 (Windows 64 bit version)

Redis.java

```
package com.redis.mogo.perftest;

import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;

public class RedisJava {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

          Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
          System.out.println("Connection to server sucessfully");
          System.out.println("Server is running: "+jedis.ping());
          int noOfElements = 500000;
          long startime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          for (int i=0;i<noOfElements;i++) {
                jedis.set(String.valueOf(i), "some fastastic value" +i);
              }
          System.out.println("Total Time to write" + noOfElements +"  is "+ ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startime)/1000));

           startime = System.currentTimeMillis();

          for (int i=0;i<noOfElements;i++) {
              jedis.get(String.valueOf(i));
            //  System.out.println(jedis.get(String.valueOf(i)));
          }

          jedis.close();
          System.out.println("Total Time to read " + noOfElements +"  is "+ ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startime)/1000));



    }


}
```

Mongo.java

```
package com.redis.mogo.perftest;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;

public class MongoJava {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("perftest");

        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("users");
          int noOfElements = 500000;

      long startime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i=0;i<noOfElements;i++) {
                BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
                document.put(String.valueOf(i), "some fastastic value" +i);
                collection.insert(document);
            }
              System.out.println("Total Time to write" + noOfElements +"  is "+ ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startime)/1000));

               startime = System.currentTimeMillis();

               int i=0;
               DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
                      while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                           String str = (String)cursor.next().get(String.valueOf(i));
                           //System.out.println(str);
                           i++;

                    }

              System.out.println("Total Time to read " + noOfElements +"  is "+ ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startime)/1000));

        collection.drop();

    }
}
```

Redis custom config file :

```
protected-mode yes
port 6379
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 0
loglevel notice
logfile "server_log.txt"
syslog-enabled yes
syslog-ident redis
databases 16
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir ./
slave-serve-stale-data yes
slave-read-only yes
repl-diskless-sync no
repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
slave-priority 100
maxmemory 10gb
appendonly no
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-max-len 128
latency-monitor-threshold 0
notify-keyspace-events ""
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-size -2
list-compress-depth 0
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit slave 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
```

Comment: You are never going to write 500K records to a cache at once.

Comment: @RobertMoskal, I agree, but how about the reads. Doesn't this prove that as the number of records increases, the performance of Mongodb is better than Redis while reading ?

Comment: That's the performance for reading 500k records from redis when redis has 500K keys? Or the performance for reading 1 record when there are 500k keys? If it's the former then again you are never going to that when caching your web app. If it's the latter, it doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 6):

Redis is used all over the world in (hundreds of) thousands of applications as a cache. It is its primary use. I never heard of MongoDB being used as a cache (you may find counter examples, I just mean it's rather unusual - it isn't even given as an example use case on [MongoDB website](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/)).

There are many good reasons for that, the first being Redis was designed from the begining to be used as a cache ([Expire](http://redis.io/commands/expire) is available from the first version), and has proven its viability in this role in many production use cases.

Some references to support this affirmation:

- From RedisLabs [usage of Redis according to cloud vendors](https://redislabs.com/redis-comparison)
- From [RedisLabs](https://redislabs.com/solutions/redis-for-caching) again:

  > Granular per key expiry mechanisms and multiple eviction policies (LRU, TTL and more) to efficiently manage objects in the cache
  >
  > Configurable notifications on expiry events for superior cache consistency and cache operations management
- [AWS doc](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/elasticache/what-is-redis/)
- [How Youporn uses Redis](http://blog.togo.io/redisphere/how-youporn-uses-redis-sfw-edition/]) ^^
- [Top 5 Redis use cases](http://objectrocket.com/blog/how-to/top-5-redis-use-cases)

And I could continue with a very, very long list.

Moreover, writing relevant benchmarks is very difficult, and comments on your question prove it once again. For them to be relevant, you must write benchmarks matching the exact use cases you will use in production, with a similar hardware and software configuration. Writing 500k items then reading them does not sound like a production use case.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is designed to be used as a cache solution because it keeps complete data in Main memory (RAM). Mongo DB should be used if you want persistence storage of your data.

One of the application I worked on where we are using Mongo db to persist TB's of data, and Redis db as a cache solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Redis to has a mechanism to persist data in the database as files. the point I am making here is that Mongodb is much fast in retrieval and storing data so why not use Mongo instead of Redis.

Comment: Mongo db has much complex architecture and it is designed to be for persistent storage, you also need to look into the how you invalidate your cache, in Redis you can define "TTL" for the cached objects.

Comment: below code has issues  DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
                      while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                           String str = (String)cursor.next().get(String.valueOf(i));
                           //System.out.println(str);
                           i++;  you are fetching the cursor not a particular key from mongo. However you want to fetch value of a particular cached key.

Comment: yes, please refer to my last comment. You are iterating over a mongo collection to find the key you are looking for. This is not a ideal way for looking up a cached object.

Comment: amit, I am not looking up a cached object, I am iterating over every element of the collection to check how much time it takes. i do not agree with you but I agree with @Robert, this would not be the correct way to test difference between redis and mongo

Comment: Thats what I am saying, you should lookup for the cached object instead of iterating over a collection. The read time taken change if the object you are looking for is occurring in the last while you are iterating over collection. Best way for having a cache solution is provide the key and get the value.